# Is material from Adventures of Middle-Earth adaptable for Rolemaster?

Tags: conversion, rolemaster, middle-earth-role-playing, adventures-in-middle-earth

I am currently running a Rolemaster campaign set in Middle Earth, TA 1640. I have source material for Rhudaur (where the group is right now), Rivendell, and Angmar.

I have come across [this book bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/books/lord-rings-5e-final-encore-cubicle-7-books?hmb_source=navbar&hmb_medium=product_tile&hmb_campaign=tile_index_3) which features a lot of interesting regions, but the system is not Rolemaster or MERP; it is "Adventures in Middle-Earth".

Is it going to be easy to use this material for Rolemaster, or are they very different systems? What age is it set in?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. You seem to have left out the AiME tag, so I've edited it in for you (and added the [conversion] tag as well). Have you done any research into AiME already? Also, what kind of material from AiME are you asking about (e.g. setting information, or mechanical aspects such as equipment, monster/NPC statistics, etc.)?

Comment: Thank you for the editions!
I am asuming the stories I can adapt, I am more concerned about mechanical aspects and setting in time.
I don't know much about AiME, I have seen characters have 7 attributes instead of 10, but that doesn't really concern me.
Monsters have armor class and hp,but they don't seem to match the ones in Rolemaster, and I have not seen an equivalent to Offensive Bonus and Defensive Bonus, and a conversion chart for that would be useful.

Comment: https://www.rolemasterblog.com/1168-2/ - Related blog on rolemaster to 5e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is **AiME and its sister system The One Ring are not compatible with your campaign.**

AiME is a conversion of The One Ring system to the D&D 5e OGL system. I’m not familiar with rolemaster more than its a d100 system but from what I’ve gathered unless you find a 5e to Rolemaster  conversion guide they’re not really compatible. This isn’t including the additional journey, audience, and fellowship rules either.

Finally on the setting side of things the year is 2946, pg10 of the players guide of AiME, and takes place between between the Hobbit and the Lord of the Rings.

Comment: Thanks man. I might go for them just for the setting descriptions and some story ideas,your info is appreciated!

Comment: No problem. The bundle is a good one! I bought it last time it was available. It gets you every pdf except the latest one which is the Rohan guide. The game is likely going to go out of print either permanently or temporarily in the next few months due to a contract dispute sadly. So now is a great time to pick it up.